# Multimodal objective optimization

Tags: optimization

1. What is the meaning of multimodal objective optimization? 
   Could you provide an example?
2. What is the difference when compared with multi-objective optimization, which would provide solutions along the pareto front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi modal means finding multiple "optimal" solutions as opposed to just one. For example, the classic Six Hump Camelback problem has two global optima (modes), even though it is single objective.

Multi objective means you have more than one objective function. Although multi-objective problems may be aggregated into a single objective using weights, multi-objective generally means this isn't the case. Multi-objective optimization is the case where you get a Pareto front.